# Does C# support if codeblocks without braces?

Tags: c#, compilation, codeblocks, conditional-statements

How would C# compile this?

```
if (info == 8)
    info = 4;
otherStuff();
```

Would it include subsequent lines in the codeblock?

```
if (info == 8)
{
    info = 4;
    otherStuff();
}
```

Or would it take only the next line?

```
if (info == 8)
{
    info = 4;
}
otherStuff();
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, it supports it - but it takes the next *statement*, not the next *line*. So for example:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
if (someCondition) a = 1; b = 1;
int c = 2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
if (someCondition)
{
    a = 1;
}
b = 1;
int c = 2;
```

Personally I always include braces around the bodies of `if` statements, and most coding conventions I've come across take the same approach.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (info == 8)
{
    info = 4;
}
otherStuff();
```

Answer (score 4):

It works like C/C++ and Java.  Without curlies, it only includes the next statement.

Comment: Would you believe that with braces, it also only runs the next statement?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, if statements run commands based on brackets.  If no brackets are given, it runs the next command if the statement is true and then runs the command after. if the condition is false, just continues on the next command

therefore

```
if( true )
    method1();
method2();
```

would be the same as

```
if( true )
{
    method1();
}
method2();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it supports if codeblocks without braces, only the first statement after the if will be included in the if block, like in your second example

Answer (score 0):

It only takes the next line, so your example would compile to the second possible result example.