# Adding Sheets to Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to add a second sheet to an excel document where each sheet is a `Datatable`. I'm finding that while the additional sheet is added the first sheet is being wiped of data. Why is this and how do I ensure the data is not erased?

```
void Export(DataTable dt)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = null;

    object missing = Type.Missing;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = null;

    try
    {
        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
        if (firstRun)
        {
            ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
        }
        else
        {
            ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.Add();
        }

        for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Columns.Count; Idx++)
        {
            ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, Idx].Value = dt.Columns[Idx].ColumnName;
        }
        for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Rows.Count; Idx++)
        {  
            ws.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dt.Columns.Count].Value =
            dt.Rows[Idx].ItemArray;
        }

        if (!firstRun)
        {
            excel.Visible = true;
            wb.Activate();
        }
        firstRun = false;
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error accessing Excel: " + ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick check - can you put the `{` and `}` parenthesis around the first if/else condition and check whether it has fixed it? + I think that `firstRun` is always `false`?

Comment: Put `excel.Visible = true;` earlier in the code, and then step through it line by line to see what code is causing the clearing.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks, led me to the solution. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty silly mistake, it was because I was adding a new Workbook each time which was overwriting everything. Moving out the initialising worked.

```
void initExcel()
    {
        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
    }
void AddToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (firstRun)
            {
                ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
            }
            else
            {
                ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.Add();
            }

            for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Columns.Count; Idx++)
            {
                ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, Idx].Value = dt.Columns[Idx].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Rows.Count; Idx++)
            {  
                ws.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dt.Columns.Count].Value =
                dt.Rows[Idx].ItemArray;
            }

            if (lastRun)
            {
                excel.Visible = true;
                wb.Activate();
            }
            firstRun = false;
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error accessing Excel: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `dt` is not assigned correctly to the correct `worksheet`. Thus,                 `ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, Idx].Value = dt.Columns[Idx].ColumnName;` is taking `Null` values into `ws` and thus it is erasing the data.

---

Pretty much, I am quite sure that your error is due to the fact, that you are not using `{` and `}` after the first condition.

Use them wisely - [Does C# support if codeblocks without braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345867/does-c-sharp-support-if-codeblocks-without-braces)

Comment: It is definitely not this. I'll update my code in any case.