# 1 == 0 returns True. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been tracing an issue for a bit, and it turned out it was caused by an if-condition where apparently `1 == 0` returns True. I'm curious as to what exactly went wrong there?

[image: Apparently 1 == 0]

`currentChapter` = 1, and `selectedChapter` = 0 but the break point seems to be reached anyway.

I fixed the issue by adding the following braces:

```
    if (currentChapter == selectedChapter)
    {
        SelectPage(selectedButton);
    }
```

**But**, the fix doesn't really make sense to me. According to *@jon-skeet*'s answer on this question: [*Does C# support if codeblocks without braces?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345867/does-c-sharp-support-if-codeblocks-without-braces)

> Yes, it supports it - but it takes the next statement, not the next line.

In accordance, the next statement should be `SelectPage(selectedButton)`, which therefore should be ignored if the if-statement returns false.

What am I missing here? I'm mainly concerned that this behavior may repeat in the future as I'm used to not adding braces when they do not seem necessary.

Comment: Can/did you remove the braces to see if it stops working again?

Comment: @Sweeper I just removed the braces again and tested, the issue no longer happens. Is this some sort of malfunction within Visual Studio itself?

Comment: @RemonRamy I would assume so. It could be that you were running an old version of the code, and that the version that you were looking at has not been compiled.

Comment: @CaptainWibble Not at all, I did not. Which is why this is confusing me quite a bit.

Comment: @Sweeper I see, I'll make sure to keep an eye out of Unity-VS integration in the future for similar cases. I was mainly concerned this could happen again and have me tracing my steps pointlessly.

Comment: Aside from a bug in the Unity3D-VS integration, there could be other reasons for the issue, depending on the concrete code of your program and its runtime behavior. One such a possibility could be currentChapter and/or selectedChapter being a property (i don't know, but you know whether they are or aren't properties) with a getter that has a nasty side-effect of changing the property value (this should be rather easy to figure out by setting a breakpoint on the getters). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Another possibility is that the effect could occur do to a race condition, with one thread modifying either currentChapter or selectedChapter while another thread executes the `if` statement. Whether this is the case or not can often be hard to find out by experiment, but a clear sign of race conditions is the problem not occuring every time you would expect it to, but only sometimes (with "sometimes" i mean the full span between "very often" and "rather rare")...